# Why does this error occur when compiling with SBT?

Tags: scala

just like this:

```
unreachable code due to variable pattern
```

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a82Fo.png)

I know how to solve it , but I don't why?
It's a bug of  compiler?

Comment: Could you please show full code block where this error happening, probably that you are using d1 two times in the same block, so `d1` can be a simple solution

Comment: Given the amount of code you posted, I would guess due aliens. Given the image you posted _(which btw it is against the rules posting images)_ it is because you have a previous match of the form `case d =>` which already matches everything, thus the later match `case _` is redundant since it will never be reached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to understand is given a sequence of patterns, then the [first](https://www.artima.com/pins1ed/case-classes-and-pattern-matching.html) pattern that matches wins whilst the rest are ignored

> A match expression is evaluated by trying each of the patterns in the
>   order they are written. The first pattern that matches is selected,
>   and the part following the arrow is selected and executed.

For example, consider [variable pattern](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/08-pattern-matching.html#variable-patterns) `pattern2` below which matches any value

```
(42: Any) match {
  case pattern1: String => "first pattern1 was tried but did not match"
  case pattern2         => "then pattern2 was tried and it did indeed match"
  case pattern3: Int    => "so pattern3 was not tried because pattern2 already won"
}
```

then `pattern3` will never be attempted and the whole match expression evaluates to

```
then pattern2 was tried and it did indeed match
```

whilst compiler raises a warning

```
Warning:(19, 28) unreachable code due to variable pattern 'pattern2' on line 22
  case pattern3: Int    => "so pattern3 was not tried because pattern2 already won"
```

This is not a bug, but simply the way compiler is specified to work to avoid bad or unreachable code that is never going to be executed. Another way of thinking about it is to imagine pattern matching to be a chain of `if-else`s

```
if (cond1) {
  "first cond1 was tried but did not match"
} else if (cond2) {
  "then cond2 was tried and it did indeed match"
} else if (cond3) {
  "so cond3 was not tried because cond2 already won"
} else {
  // crash
}
```